# Deep-reverse for trees in Scheme (Lisp)

Tags: data-structures, tree, lisp, scheme, reverse

I have a deep reverse for a basic tree data structure in Scheme

```
(define (deep-reverse t)
  (cond ((null? t) '())
        ((not (pair? t)) t)  
        (else (cons (deep-reverse (cdr t)) (deep-reverse (car t))))))

(define stree (cons (list 1 2) (list 3 4)))
1 ]=> (deep-reverse stree)
;Value: (((() . 4) . 3) (() . 2) . 1)
```

I feel like a cleaner, better result would be:

```
(4 3 (2 1))
```

Can anyone provide some guidance as to where I'm going wrong in my deep-reverse function? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's better to split the task into simple operations instead of trying to do all at once. What you want to achieve can be described like this: Reverse the current list itself, then deep-reverse all sublists in it (or the other way round, the order of the two steps doesn't really matter. I choose this order because it results in nicer formatting of the source code).

Now, there already is a function in the standard library for simply reversing a list, `reverse`. So all you need to do is to combine that with the recursion on those elements that are sublists:

```
(define (deep-reverse t)
  (map (lambda (x)
         (if (list? x)
             (deep-reverse x)
             x))
       (reverse t)))
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. I am trying to avoid library functions (don't know if that is even a good idea) where possible, but reversing a list is something I do know how to do in Scheme.

Comment: do you mind explaining the code a bit? I think if I study it I'll understand, but it is not intuitive to me, yet.

Comment: The explanation is mostly already in the answer. Things you might not know yet, I guess: `map` applies a function to every element of a list, and returns the results in a new list. `lambda` defines an anonymous function.

Comment: @zallarak Don't avoid the basic list-processing library; spotting opportunities to use it is as important as anything. Using general purpose utility functions is the right way, and if you don't learn to use them you're doing it wrong—solutions without the library functions are unnecessarily hard to write and read. What you can do, however, is try at first to also write your own version of any library function you use.  In this case, you'd solve your original problem just like Rörd did, and then as an additional exercise write your own implementations of `map` and `reverse`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(define (deep-reverse t)
  (let loop ((t t)
             (acc '()))
    (cond ((null? t) acc)
          ((not (pair? t)) t)
          (else (loop (cdr t)
                      (cons (loop (car t) '()) acc))))))
```

Call it like this:

```
(define stree (cons (list 1 2) (list 3 4)))
(deep-reverse stree)
> (4 3 (2 1))
```

For creating a reversed list, one technique is to accumulate the answer in a parameter (I usually call it `acc`). Since we're operating on a list of lists, the recursion has to be called on both the `car` and the `cdr` part of the list. Lastly, I'm using a *named let* as a shorthand for avoiding the creation of an extra function, but the same result could be obtained by defining a helper function with two parameters, the tree and the accumulator:

```
(define (deep-reverse t)
  (aux t '()))

(define (aux t acc)
  (cond ((null? t) acc)
        ((not (pair? t)) t)
        (else (aux (cdr t)
                   (cons (aux (car t) '()) acc)))))
```

Comment: Thank you for those explanations Oscar. I'm not familiar with loop yet, you've supplied me with some cool functions.

Answer (score 0):

I think it better to reverse a list based on its element count:
an empty list is reverse, a single element list is also reverted, more than 1 element is concatenation of the reverse of tail and head.

```
(defun deep-reverse (tree)
   (cond ((zerop (length tree)) nil)
         ((and (= 1 (length tree)) (atom (car tree))) tree)
         ((consp (car tree)) (append (deep-reverse (cdr tree)) 
                                     (list (deep-reverse (car tree)))))
         (t (append (deep-reverse (cdr tree)) (list (car tree))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```lisp
(define (deep-reverse tree)
  (define (deep-reverse-iter items acc)
    (cond
      ((null? items) acc)
      ((not (pair? items)) items)
      (else (deep-reverse-iter
        (cdr items)
        (cons (deep-reverse (car items)) acc)))))
  (deep-reverse-iter tree ()))

(define x (list (list 1 2) (list 3 4 (list 5 6))))

(newline)
(display (deep-reverse x))
```

It prints `(((6 5) 4 3) (2 1))` as expected and uses the minimum of standard library functions: `pair?` to check if the tree is a `cons` and `null?` to check for an empty tree/list.

This solution for trees is a generalization of the `reverse` function for lists:

```lisp
(define (reverse items)
  (define (reverse-iter items acc)
    (cond
      ((null? items) acc)
      ((not (pair? items)) items)
      (else (reverse-iter (cdr items) (cons (car items) acc)))))
  (reverse-iter items ()))
```

the difference being that `deep-reverse` is also applied to `car items`