# How to make deep-reverse function in Lisp

Tags: recursion, lisp, common-lisp, reverse

I am trying to make deep-reverse function in lisp.    For example:

```
(a (b c d) e) -> (e (d c b) a)
```

Here is my code.

```
(defun deeprev (l)
  (cond ((null l) nil)
        ((list (car l)) (append (deeprev (cdr l)) (deeprev (car l))))
        (t (append (deeprev (cdr l))(car l)))
  )
)
```

Whenever I compile and load, I have an error:

> Error: Attempt to take the car of E which is not listp

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8797601/124319

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4102996/124319

Answer (score 4):

The easiest option would be to just `REVERSE` the current list, and use `MAPCAR` to reverse all sublist with the same function.

```
(defun tree-reverse (tree)
  "Deep reverse TREE if it's a list. If it's an atom, return as is."
  (if (listp tree)
      (mapcar #'tree-reverse
              (reverse tree))
      tree))

(tree-reverse '(a (b c d) e)) ;=> (E (D C B) A)
```

Answer (score 3):

In your function, you assume that if the `l` input variable is not `nil`, then it is necessarily a cons-cell, because you unconditionally takes `(car l)` inside the `(list ...)` function. That's why you have an error. There are many other things that are not `nil` which could be bound to `l` at this point, like numbers or symbols.

By the way, `(list ...)` just builds a list, you would need to use `listp` instead. Since you ruled out the `nil` case and a list is defined as either `nil` or a `cons`, you could have used also `consp`.

Comment: Thank you!! But I don't know how to fix (list (car l)) part... :(